# Random images and display it in a div

Tags: jquery

I found this great plugin that pulls random images and display it in a div.

Se author link,

http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/jquery-plugin-random-image-on-page-load/

Is it possible to get the random images to fade in?

```
(function($){

    $.randomImage = {
        defaults: {

            //you can change these defaults to your own preferences.
            path: 'images/', //change this to the path of your images
            myImages: ['containerBg.png', 'containerBg2.png'] //put image names in this bracket. ex: 'harold.jpg', 'maude.jpg', 'etc'

        }           
    }

    $.fn.extend({
            randomImage:function(config) {

                var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config); 

                 return this.each(function() {

                        var imageNames = config.myImages;

                        //get size of array, randomize a number from this
                        // use this number as the array index

                        var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;

                        var lotteryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*imageNamesSize);

                        var winnerImage = imageNames[lotteryNumber];

                        var fullPath = config.path + winnerImage;


                        //put this image into DOM at class of randomImage
                        // alt tag will be image filename.
                        $(this).attr( {
                                        src: fullPath,
                                        alt: winnerImage
                                    });


                }); 
            }

    });
```

How can I modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the last few lines:

```
                    $(this).attr( {
                                    src: fullPath,
                                    alt: winnerImage
                                });
```

With this:

```
                    $(this).css('opacity',0.01).attr( {
                                    src: fullPath,
                                    alt: winnerImage
                                }).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a plugin.
Very short [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/XtXGm/1/) for you.

Comment: @Åke please, approve the answer ;)